# Mid Function for Microsoft Excel to obtain column .txt file

Tags: string, excel, text

Captain Morgan  ------            Insane Journeys     --------             A-

I have easily gotten the left and right side parts using Left() and Right() functions.

I want to use a function in excel (not vba) that will allow me to get the middle phrase in this sentence (The dashes are really excessive spaces). can I accomplish this with a Mid() function?

This is just 1 item on a list of 80 different things in 1 column that needs to be turned into 3 columns. Every item has different character lengths. So the length counts cannot be manually entered.

Comment: Back then, when I did not know as much as now I used search&replace tool to replace too many spaces with something that will help me take it out easily ;)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Text to Columns but the image in the other answer only has one space per row while OP has some spaces that are redundant and some that are not. For this I’d suggest a modified approach:

1. Replace all pairs of spaces with a character unlikely to be encountered – I’d suggest a pipe.
2. Apply Text to Columns with pipe as delimiter.
3. Apply [TRIM](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/trim-function-HA102752831.aspx) to the middle column to remove any remaining redundant spaces (eg =TRIM(B1) copied down and then that column pasted as values over the source).

But to answer `can I accomplish this with a Mid() function?` I think yes though not cost effective for  a mere 80 entries when there is a viable alternative.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use "Text to columns" from Data Tab. It has option to split data to different columns using various criteria.

[image]

All you need to do is select data you want to split to columns and select criteria you need.

In your case it can be either `Space` or `Other:`. When you select `Other:` you can add your own criteria like "space dot space" or anything you need.

For more detailed information you can [enter this link.](http://www.blueleafsoftware.com/Products/Dagra/PasteDigitizedExcel.php)

Comment: Please provide examples as well for the OP to understand.

Comment: @sshashank124 hope that makes it clearer than before.